# convert an array like looking string into array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I want to convert array like looking string into array.

for ex:

from string

```
 var str = "['Asian', 'Japanese', 'Vegetarian Friendly', 'Vegan Options', 'Gluten Free 
   Options']"
```

to array

```
['Asian', 'Japanese', 'Vegetarian Friendly', 'Vegan Options', 'Gluten Free Options']
```

I have tried this with regex

```
str.match(/'[a-z]*'/gi).map((elm)=>{
    return elm.replace(/'/g,"")
    })
```

but this is not considering the spaces in between or more than one word.

Please let me know the efficient solution.

Comment: Do you have it inside a larger string?

Comment: I'm reading this string from an CSV file using PapaParse. and in csv file data is stored like ['Asian', 'Japanese', 'Vegetarian Friendly', 'Vegan Options', 'Gluten Free 
   Options'] in a single cell

Comment: You can replace all the `'` to `"` and then `JSON.parse`. But if you have an apostrophe on any of the items, then it won't work

Comment: Use `'[^']*'`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the single quotes to double quotes, and convert to array with `JSON.parse()`:

```js
var str = "['Asian', 'Japanese', 'Vegetarian Friendly', 'Vegan Options', 'Gluten Free Options ']"

var result = JSON.parse(str.replace(/'/g, '"'))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) all single quotes by double quotes and [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it:

```js
let str = "['Asian', 'Japanese', 'Vegetarian Friendly', 'Vegan Options', 'Gluten Free Options']";

str = str.replace(/'/g,'"') // replace all ' by "

let arr = JSON.parse(str) // now that it's valid JSON, parse it

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "['Asian', 'Japanese', 'Vegetarian Friendly', 'Vegan Options', 'Gluten Free Options ']";
console.log(JSON.parse(str.replace(/'/g, '"')));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str.replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'').split(', ')
```

Try this.
It is working for the string you posted.